# Is there a keybinding in vscode for add import to an existing import statement or how to add imports on the fly in vscode?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, visual-studio-code

Seems like current extensions on VSCode marketplace **can not properly add** angular imports. For instance, when I add OnInit using Path IntelliSense extension

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
```

It imports it from

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/core'
```

Instead of

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core'
```

As it should. I tried looking through extensions on the marketplace but failed to find anything remotely workable. I noticed however that VSCode provides a functionality to add to an existing import statement which you can see in the screenshot here

[image]
Is there any way to use a keybinding for this without the need to click a yellow light bulb when it appears and manually selecting it? And/Or do you perhaps know a great extension that adds Angular imports correctly like WebStorm does? (one of few reasons I am still resorting to use WebStorm over VSCode that is lighter & faster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your cursor is at the type you want to import, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (I guess on Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> ).

This is possible with TypeScript 2.2. Before that, a lot of people used this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero